# DB2express with MQ on Docker

Tags: docker, db2, ibm-mq

I want to create trigger on my db2 table. Trigger will send message on queue. I did this with my IBM MQ on Docker + db2 z/os on mainframe. But now I want all do this on my laptop on docker. But i can't find good image on dockerhub (with db2express-c and mq). 
Command *enable_MQFunctions* on my db2express-c is, of course, not working because Db2 can't find MQ lib 
*(enable_MQFunctions: error while loading shared libraries: libmqm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)*
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no examples of IBM MQ + DB2 in a single container image. There are example images of IBM MQ in a container and the source for it is [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container).

You will have to take the source and modify it to install DB2 as well and then modify the command program ([runmqserver](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/tree/master/cmd/runmqserver)) to also set up DB2.